# How do I parent these two bones in the hip the same way they are at the shoulder? Can I?

Tags: rigging, bones, parent

How can I make it so the lowest circle thing (armature?) on the bones in the spine is the parent of the highest armature in the leg? Is that even something I can do? When I try to parent it in the settings for the Bone, it parents it to the bone directly above the bone instead of the one under it.

What I have now
[image: what i have now]

What happens when I try to parent it.
[image: what happens when i try to parent it]

Answer (score 1):

Your bone is correctly parented, when a bone is parented (child), there's a dotted line that goes from its head to the tail of its parent. So maybe I haven't understood your question correctly but it looks like you're good.

Comment: I wanted it to parent like this
https://imgur.com/a/HiKhEJ4

But when I think about it, I think you're right, and that this may be better for posing anyways. Thanks!